# Problem While installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, usb-drive

I was installing Ubuntu 12.10 from a Pen drive on Sony Vaio(Model is: SVE151D11L. 64 bit i3 processor) using an ISO image. I made the pendrive bootable by using "Universal USB Installer". The System starts booting from the pendrive but it gets stuck on the UBUNTU start screen(the one with dots).

On Pressing ESC at that screen, It shows:

```
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
...
```

I've been trying for hours, tried installing 13.04 instead, the same problem occurred again.

Please Help me out.

**EDIT**

I opened it in another computer the pen drive worked fine.

Comment: Which sony vaio version are you using and is it 32 or 64bit? I believe that it is a graphics driver problem.

Comment: Model is: SVE151D11L. 64 bit i3 processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have spare PC then I would try to use that USB on that spare PC and see if it boots up there. If it boots up there then something is wrong with your laptop otherwise it's an issue with your USB.

If it is USB then I can think of couple of reasons,

1. Ubuntu copied on USB is screwed up somehow, I would try to create another installation on same USB.
2. If your USB has U3 support then remove it first and then try it.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it was working on another laptop but not on mine. So the usb is perfect.

Comment: From what I understand this error clearly means that system has issues with reading some specific block of device SR0 (which I would guess is your USB). In your second PC, did you just opened USB or tried to boot using it ? (your edit doesn't mention about booting so just confirming)

Comment: I booted with the USB on the other PC and Ubuntu had started as it should. So problem with USB looks improbable. Can this be a problem with the USB port?

Comment: It could be. Try to plug USB on another port and see if that helps.

Comment: Using a different Port and different version(12.04LTS) worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sr0 represents the first SCSI CD/DVD-ROM device connected to the system.

You could try is to use this software to create you Ubuntu USB:
[Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

It will set up the boot sector and everything for you. I use it all the time.

I recommend running the FAT32 formatting option on your USB if you don't have any persistent data you'd like to keep on your USB stick.